# Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Express'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, express, angular-universal

In VS Code, for an Angular 13 app using Angular Universal for Server Side Rendering I get the following error:

```
Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Express'.ts(2339)
```

in the line: `server.listen(port, () => {` of the file `server.ts` shown below:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow();
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
import 'globalthis/auto';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/src';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/bbc/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
```

Typescript 4.4 is used. Any ideas on what I should change in the `server.ts` file?

Comment: You're returning an _Application_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, any practical suggestions?

Comment: Change the return type to reflect that? An Application _does_ have a listen property: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/888c4b6f723525409786568079e25546e6989b6f/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L1183-L1205

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error a while ago when i updated angular 11 > 14. I started to remove a lot of unnecessary code and deprecated packages in package.json which resulted in a lot of errors :P After two hours of blood sweat and tears i finally manged to make the app work again with angular 14. I stumbled across the same error you got and started to look at the imports on the top of your file and I realized that some packages where missing. I re:added them and the error went away. I Hope you manage to solve the issue :D